# Why isn't this global variable set inside an anonymous function?

Tags: php, global-variables, anonymous-function

```
$GLOBALS['failed'] = "no";

set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr) {
    $GLOBALS['failed'] = "yes";
});

a_function_that_triggers_the_above_function();

echo $GLOBALS['failed']."\n"; # => "no"
```

That anonymous function is triggered, I'm 100% sure. Why isn't the GLOBALS value changed?

Comment: Works for me too. We'll have to assume that `a_function_that_triggers_an_error();` failed to fulfil its evil task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you are doing in your specific function that triggers an error, but using this portion of code :

```
$GLOBALS['failed'] = "no";

set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr) {
    var_dump('handler !');
    var_dump($errstr);
    $GLOBALS['failed'] = "yes";
});

echo 10 / 0;

var_dump($GLOBALS['failed']);
```

I get the following output :

```
string 'handler !' (length=9)
string 'Division by zero' (length=16)
string 'yes' (length=3)
```

Which shows that :

- The handler function is actually called
- The global variable is affected.

*(I'm using PHP 5.3.2)*

Comment: I was printing out the globals variable before calling the function that triggered the change.

Comment: @randomguy oh ^^ so you have solved your problem, I guess ;-)